# What is the location of Anaconda config to specify the location of ODBC drivers?

Tags: python, macos, odbc, anaconda, vertica

I need to install Vertica's ODBC driver [here](https://my.vertica.com/download/vertica/client-drivers/) but it installs to different location than my custom path

```
$ which python
/Users/hhh/anaconda3/bin/python
```

I could fix the problem by uninstalling Anaconda and installing Anaconda under the same place as macOS default python but it can mess the system.

**What is the location of the Anaconda config file that specifies the location of ODBC drivers?**